# Filter stackoverflow.com dashboard

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Can I filter stackoverflow.com dashboard ?

I mean, can I see questions related to 'python' or 'ruby' only on dashboard (when I am logged in) ?

Also, I am not sure if this is the right place to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags to filter out results. But this sort of question is better asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

To filter tags, you can add them to your ignored tag, and this will remove questions with those tags from the home page and search results.

You can also add favorite tags, which highlights questions that may be interesting to you.